# Using Icon Fonts as Markers in Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, font-awesome, icon-fonts

I was wondering whether it is possible to use icon font icons (e.g. Font Awesome) as markers in Google Maps V3 to replace the default marker. To show/insert them in a HTML or PHP document the code for the marker would be:

```
<i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, one way of doing it would be to extract the SVG properties from Font Awesome icons, and then define `google.maps.Symbol` using SVG notation. Then you'd be able to use them as symbols

Comment: That's a good idea - after extracting the icon path and some modifications, I was able to create the desired effect. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: No worries, if you have time you could get them all into a `Font Awesome Google Maps` thing and host them on Github/Bitbucket. I think the Font Awesome license would permit that.

Comment: Afaik folks are already working on making the font Google Maps compatible. To take advantage of it in the meantime open font-awesome.svg in an editor and search for the desired icon statement. Then copy the SVG path and it to define a custom polygon in google maps. Check the Google Maps V3 reference / code examples for details.

Comment: I know how to do it, just don't have the time to do it. There's a font set by Mapbox called `Maki`. I'm thinking of porting that into SVG

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's my attempt at the same thing (using "markerwithlabel" utility library) before I realised Nathan did the same more elegantly above: http://jsfiddle.net/f3xchecf/

```
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( 50, 50 ),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },

        map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), myOptions ),

     marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: myLatLng,
       draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: true,
       icon: ' ',
       map: map,
         labelContent: '<i class="fa fa-send fa-3x" style="color:rgba(153,102,102,0.8);"></i>',
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 50)
     });

    marker.setMap( map );
}

initialize();
```

Comment: this is nice bc it doesn't require the additional js, but I like both solutions.

Comment: I tried to get this to work but does not work nor does it work in fiddel. Do you have an updated solution?

Comment: @Aaron you need to use the github library linked in the other answer. https://github.com/nathan-muir/fontawesome-markers

Answer (score 81):

I just had the same problem - decided to do a quick and dirty conversion and host on github.

https://github.com/nathan-muir/fontawesome-markers

You can manually include the JS file, or use `npm install fontawesome-markers` or `bower install fontawesome-markers`.

Just include the javascript file `fontawesome-markers.min.js` and you can use them like so:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: {
        path: fontawesome.markers.EXCLAMATION,
        scale: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 0.2,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: '#f8ae5f',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    },
    clickable: false,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
});
```

Edit (April-2016): There's now packages for v4.2 -> v4.6.1

Comment: +1 for keeping the script updated over a year later!

Comment: Nice.  I found it usefull to offset the icon like:
anchor: new google.maps.Point(30,-30)

Comment: fontawesome-markers.4.6.1.min.js - https://github.com/veteze/fontawesome-markers/blob/patch-1/fontawesome-markers.4.6.1.min.js

Comment: I think its worth mentioning that the js file is 0.5 MB large.

Comment: I cannot find [GRADUATION_CAP icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/graduation-cap/) in the [fontawesome-markers.min.js v4.6.1 script file](https://github.com/nathan-muir/fontawesome-markers/blob/master/fontawesome-markers.min.js), which was introduced with font-awesome v4.1.

Comment: it has an alias - MORTAR_BOARD

Answer (score 46):

I know this is an old post, but just in case you can use the `MarkerLabel` object now:

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    label: {
        fontFamily: 'Fontawesome',
        text: '\uf299'
    }
});
```

Worked for me.

[image: See fontawesome icon on google map marker].

[Reference Google Maps Maker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel)

Comment: Thanks dude, with this there is no need to use any external plugin.

Comment: This is really confusing. You are talking about the markerLABEL not the marker.

Comment: You can define the label obj as option for the Marker. As per doc "Adds a label to the marker. The label can either be a string, or a MarkerLabel object."

Comment: This is legit! I didn't want the pinkish marker, so I just set the `Marker.icon = '  '` a single space, as done in Jason's answer. The [MarkerLabel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel) can take all kinds of styles including fontSize and color to customize the icon. So simple. Thanks @guido!

Comment: For higher versions of the API, if above code doesn't work, just further enclose 'Fontawesome' with double quotes "'Fontawesome'" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50256889/google-maps-v3-fontawesome5/51788072#51788072

Answer (score 23):

### The light weight solution

- fontawesome-markers: `480kb`
- markerwithlabel: `25kb`

To avoid these dependencies, simple go to [fontawesome-markers](https://github.com/nathan-muir/fontawesome-markers), find the path for the icon you want, and include it as follows:

```
var icon = {
    path: "M27.648-41.399q0-3.816-2.7-6.516t-6.516-2.7-6.516 2.7-2.7 6.516 2.7 6.516 6.516 2.7 6.516-2.7 2.7-6.516zm9.216 0q0 3.924-1.188 6.444l-13.104 27.864q-.576 1.188-1.71 1.872t-2.43.684-2.43-.684-1.674-1.872l-13.14-27.864q-1.188-2.52-1.188-6.444 0-7.632 5.4-13.032t13.032-5.4 13.032 5.4 5.4 13.032z",
    fillColor: '#E32831',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: 0.65
}

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    icon: icon
});
```

Comment: You can also go to https://fontawesome.com/icons to download the svg for any icon and get the path.

Answer (score 13):

In a modern browser one can use the canvas in order to render the font to png, and then use the data URI scheme:

```
  function getIcon(glyph, color) {
    var canvas, ctx;
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = canvas.height = 20;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (color) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    }
    ctx.font = '20px FontAwesome';
    ctx.fillText(glyph, 0, 16);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
  }
```

For example: `getIcon("\uf001")` for the music note.

Comment: `ctx.fillStyle = color;`, or `ctx.strokeText` instead of `ctx.fillText`

Answer (score 9):

If you want **the awesomefont MARKER with an awesomefont ICON INSIDE**:

**1.** copy the [SVG path of the awesomefont marker](https://fontawesome.com/icons/map-marker?style=solid) (click download and copy the SVG path) and use it as `icon` (remember to credit the authors, see [license](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)). 
Then you can change it's color to anything you want.

**2.** As `label` you only insert the awesome font icon code and the color you want.

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function init() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.509865, -0.118092)
    });
    var icon = {
        path: "M172.268 501.67C26.97 291.031 0 269.413 0 192 0 85.961 85.961 0 192 0s192 85.961 192 192c0 77.413-26.97 99.031-172.268 309.67-9.535 13.774-29.93 13.773-39.464 0z", //SVG path of awesomefont marker
        fillColor: '#333333', //color of the marker
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        scale: 0.09, //size of the marker, careful! this scale also affects anchor and labelOrigin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(200,510), //position of the icon, careful! this is affected by scale
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(205,190) //position of the label, careful! this is affected by scale
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      map: map,
      icon: icon,
      label: {
        fontFamily: "'Font Awesome 5 Free'",
        text: '\uf0f9', //icon code
        fontWeight: '900', //careful! some icons in FA5 only exist for specific font weights
        color: '#FFFFFF', //color of the text inside marker
      },
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
```

Comment: This is pretty great.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: From where I can get code like `uf0f9`? As I want different icons on map.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to import the svgs directly from [@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons) and use the [Icon Interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon).

```js
import { faMapMarkerAlt } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

function initMap(): void {
  const center = { lat: 0, lng: 0 };

  const map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement,
    {
      zoom: 9,
      center,
    }
  );

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
    map,
    icon: {
      path: faMapMarkerAlt.icon[4] as string,
      fillColor: "#0000ff",
      fillOpacity: 1,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(
        faMapMarkerAlt.icon[0] / 2, // width
        faMapMarkerAlt.icon[1] // height
      ),
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: "#ffffff",
      scale: 0.075,
    },
  });
}
```

Can try it at: https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/googlemaps/js-samples/tree/sample-marker-modern

Answer (score 3):

I've put together a simple JS library that generates nice SVG markers using the Font Awesome icons. https://github.com/jawj/MapMarkerAwesome

Comment: Nice!  Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

All I seen looks good, but they would not work for me; However, this worked smoothly and is small.

Use a link out to wherever your font awesome library is.

The normal marker javascript code is fine and add the icon attribute.

// The marker

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

position: uluru,

icon: 'https://cdn.mapmarker.io/api/v1/pin?icon=fa-truck&size=50&hoffset=0&color=%23FFFFFF&background=%23FF7500&voffset=-1',

```
map: map,
```

});

}

You can change the font awesome icon, position, color, etc. right there in the icon: attribute.