# Geolocation and font awesome

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, geolocation

I'm using the Geolocation API and would like to set a marker on my map but instead of displaying the standard icon I'd like to use an icon from bootstrap and Font Awesome. Example code of marker:

```
var musicMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: musicCoords,
                map: map,
                title: "Music",
                icon: "<i class='icon-music'></i>"
            });
```

Can it be done and if so how? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Icon Fonts as Markers in Google Maps V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375077/using-icon-fonts-as-markers-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: Thank you, that post did indeed answer my question. Work perfectly.