# How to display popover text on click with google maps utility library?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on an app which uses google maps to display the location of certain types of crimes that have been committed in a given area.

I wanted to be able to use Font Awesome icons as markers on the map, and I was able to use the google maps utility library (v3) to do this based off of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375077/using-icon-fonts-as-markers-in-google-maps-v3).

However, in using this method, specifically the `MarkerWithLabel` class, I cannot figure out how to properly display the content popover when clicking on my icon markers. I looked through the [source code](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js) for this class but do not see any parameters which allow for this functionality.

I tried to make my Fontawesome Icon markers into buttons which toggle a popover but that did not work and no errors were shown in the console. So I then tried making the icon marker button toggle a modal. However, strangely, I am only able to toggle the modal when I click *and* drag the icon across the map, rather than simply on click. I would rather not allow the icon markers to be draggable but this is the only way I have been able to figure out how to toggle the modal.

Here is the google maps utility library I am referencing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
```

And here is my code:

```
<h1>Safety Map</h1>
<div id="map-canvas" class="map"></div>

<div class="modal fade modal-small " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="mySmallModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div> <!-- .modal-header -->

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, quasi voluptas nostrum culpa sunt laboriosam corporis perspiciatis animi rem unde. Nihil, doloribus soluta possimus non asperiores eius natus quaerat porro.</p>
            </div> <!-- .modal-body -->

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-ar btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-ar btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div> <!-- .modal-footer -->
        </div> <!-- .modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- .modal-dialog -->
</div>

<script>
    function initialize() {
        var crimes = <?php echo json_encode($crimes); ?>;
        var count = crimes.length;

        var mapCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng( 50, 50 );
        var myOptions = {
                            zoom: 14,
                            center: mapCoordinates,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };

       var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), myOptions );

        for(x = 0; x < count; x++)
        {
            var coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng( crimes[x].lat, crimes[x].lng );
            marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                title: crimes[x].type, //tooltip
                draggable: true,       //I'd rather not have this set to true
                clickable: true,
                position: coordinates,
                icon: ' ',
                map: map,
                labelContent: '<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal-small" class="btn btn-transparent fa fa-ambulance" style="color:rgba(144,15,15,0.8);"></button>',                  
                labelClass: "labels" // the CSS class for the label
            });

            marker.setMap( map );
        }
    }

    initialize();

</script>
```

Does anyone know why I cannot toggle the modal on click? Maybe there is a better way to do this? I simply want to be able to display some marker specific text once a user clicks on an icon marker on the map, whether that is with a popover or modal or similar method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was basically looking for a way to implement the [`InfoWindow` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) functionality but with the google maps utility library. The class I was looking for was [`InfoBox`](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/).

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jehj3/597/) of how to use it.