# Font Awesome icon as marker in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, font-awesome

I want to use a font awesome icon as Google Maps marker.
Here is my code:

```
function addMarker(marker) {    
    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj.geo_lat,obj.geo_lng),
    category: obj.status,
    map: map,
    icon: // Font Awesome icon here
});
```

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375077/using-icon-fonts-as-markers-in-google-maps-v3) question, but unfortunately this is not working properly for me.
I was wondering if there's another way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use [RichMarker](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-rich-marker/reference.html)

Example:

```
function addMarker(marker) {    
        marker1 = new RichMarker({ 
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj.geo_lat,obj.geo_lng),
            category: obj.status,
            map: map,   
            draggable: false,
            flat:true,
            anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
            content: '<i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i>'
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is this (without use of other external libraries):

```
marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj.geo_lat,obj.geo_lng),
    map: map,
    label: {
        fontFamily: 'Fontawesome',
        text: '\uf192', //code for font-awesome icon
        fontSize: '15px',
        color: 'red'
    },
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE, //or any others
        scale: 0
    }
});
```

Comment: just adding api doc : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel