# Using a css font-awesome marker in google maps

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a maker for google maps which uses symbols from font-awesome. I would like that it looks somehow like this:

[image]

---

I found at [Using Icon Fonts as Markers in Google Maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375077/using-icon-fonts-as-markers-in-google-maps-v3) a solution for this problem, however this requires to include a .js file which is ~0.5 MB large and thus not usable for me.

I also found this solution: https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers but I did not like the style of the markers.

I managed to create with css the following picture

[image]

```
<div style='display:inline-block;background-color:#08c;padding:10px;border-radius:20px;border:2px solid #FFF;color:#FFF;'>
    <i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to:

1. Get a nice white pointer at the bottom with CSS (as in the purple icon)
2. How to use this css marker in google maps. The best I can think of is to make a screenshot, make the black background transparent and save it as a png. But I guess there must be a more proper way to do it?

---

**EDIT:** I found in the comments from  [Using Icon Fonts as Markers in Google Maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375077/using-icon-fonts-as-markers-in-google-maps-v3)

> I don't think it's possible, one way of doing it would be to extract
>   the SVG properties from Font Awesome icons, and then define
>   google.maps.Symbol using SVG notation. Then you'd be able to use them
>   as symbols

I tried that and it failed. I am using the [bank](http://fontawesome.io/icon/university/) icon with unicode: f19c. So I opend fontawesome-webfont.svg and found an entry

```
    <glyph unicode="&#xf19c;" horiz-adv-x="2048" d="M960 1536l960 -384v-
128h-128q0 -26 -20.5 -45t-48.5 -19h-1526q-28 0 -48.5 19t-20.5 
45h-128v128zM256 896h256v-768h128v768h256v-768h128v768h256v-768h128v768h256v-
768h59q28 0 48.5 -19t20.5 -45v-64h-1664v64q0 26 20.5 45t48.5 19h59v768zM1851 
-64 q28 0 48.5 -19t20.5 -45v-128h-1920v128q0 26 20.5 45t48.5 19h1782z" />
```

Following the instructions to create [marker symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols?) I tried

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: myLatlng,
                 map: map,
                 icon: {
                   path: 'M960 1536l960 -384v-128h-128q0 -26 -20.5 -45t-48.5 
-19h-1526q-28 0 -48.5 19t-20.5 45h-128v128zM256 896h256v-768h128v768h256v-
768h128v768h256v-768h128v768h256v-768h59q28 0 48.5 -19t20.5 -45v-64h-
1664v64q0 26 20.5 45t48.5 19h59v768zM1851 -64 q28 0 48.5 -19t20.5 -45v-128h-
1920v128q0 26 20.5 45t48.5 19h1782z'
                 }
             });
```

But I do not get a bank icon, only some strange lines:
[image]

Does anyone know why I don't get an icon here? And does this maybe lead to create a icon as wished above?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:before` and `:after` selector to implement that. Check below answer.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.marker {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #08c;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
}
.marker:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14.5px;
  left: calc(50% - 16px);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 16px 16px 0;
  border-color: #fff transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="marker">
  <i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that looks nice. Could you maybe explain how this works?

Comment: `:before` and `:after` are pseudo classes. I have created 2 inverted triangles using that and positioned at the bottom to create the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed that the transition of the white border between the circle and the triangle is not smooth. Do you know how to correct that? I tried by changeing the bottom value and the values 14/16px, but I could not get it smooth.

Comment: I think I found a good solution: Remove `.marker:after` and change in `.marker:before` the property `z-index: -1` and adjust the border of `.marker`

Answer (score 2):

The path seems to be flipped vertically (you'll also need to scale it, the lines you see are just a part of a real large icon)

Fixed path:

```
M 0.19113133,-15.44788 16.905415,-8.7761997 v 2.223893 h -2.228571 q 0,0.4517349 -0.356919,0.7818476 -0.356919,0.3301132 -0.844418,0.3301132 h -26.568748 q -0.4875,0 -0.844421,-0.3301132 -0.35692,-0.3301127 -0.35692,-0.7818476 h -2.22857 v -2.223893 z M -12.066008,-4.3284126 h 4.4571411 V 9.0149371 h 2.228571 V -4.3284126 h 4.45714333 V 9.0149371 H 1.3054178 V -4.3284126 H 5.7625592 V 9.0149371 h 2.228573 V -4.3284126 H 12.448274 V 9.0149371 h 1.027233 q 0.487499,0 0.844418,0.3301126 0.356919,0.3301126 0.356919,0.7818463 v 1.111933 h -28.971426 v -1.111933 q 0,-0.4517337 0.35692,-0.7818463 0.356921,-0.3301126 0.844421,-0.3301126 h 1.027233 V -4.3284126 z M 15.704077,12.350789 q 0.4875,0 0.844418,0.330113 0.35692,0.330113 0.35692,0.781821 v 2.22392 h -33.428567 v -2.22392 q 0,-0.451708 0.356919,-0.781821 0.356919,-0.330113 0.844421,-0.330113 h 31.025889 z
```

```js
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: mapOptions.center,
                 map: map,
                 icon: {
                   xscale:.2,
                   fillColor:'#000000',
                   fillOpacity:.5,
                   path: 'M 0.19113133,-15.44788 16.905415,-8.7761997 v 2.223893 h -2.228571 q 0,0.4517349 -0.356919,0.7818476 -0.356919,0.3301132 -0.844418,0.3301132 h -26.568748 q -0.4875,0 -0.844421,-0.3301132 -0.35692,-0.3301127 -0.35692,-0.7818476 h -2.22857 v -2.223893 z M -12.066008,-4.3284126 h 4.4571411 V 9.0149371 h 2.228571 V -4.3284126 h 4.45714333 V 9.0149371 H 1.3054178 V -4.3284126 H 5.7625592 V 9.0149371 h 2.228573 V -4.3284126 H 12.448274 V 9.0149371 h 1.027233 q 0.487499,0 0.844418,0.3301126 0.356919,0.3301126 0.356919,0.7818463 v 1.111933 h -28.971426 v -1.111933 q 0,-0.4517337 0.35692,-0.7818463 0.356921,-0.3301126 0.844421,-0.3301126 h 1.027233 V -4.3284126 z M 15.704077,12.350789 q 0.4875,0 0.844418,0.330113 0.35692,0.330113 0.35692,0.781821 v 2.22392 h -33.428567 v -2.22392 q 0,-0.451708 0.356919,-0.781821 0.356919,-0.330113 0.844421,-0.330113 h 31.025889 z'
                 }
             });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,body,#map_canvas{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```

However, it will not be possible to achieve the desired result, because you would need multiple pathes(but only a single path is possible). You will need a custom overlay(e.g. https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker) to use fontawesome(the css-approach will not work with native markers, because they are based on either a complex `<canvas/>` or `<img/>`...where `::before/::after` are not applicable)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Currently it seems to be the best approach is to do a screenshot of the CSS result obtained by Pugaz. It looks unfortunately very pixelated.