# Can I use awesome font in a URL request?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, font-awesome

I am setting map markers and I want to add awesome font marker. 
I am using a 3rd party api (OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier
) that requires the marker URL.

Right now I am getting a local marker, marker.svg. But I want to use awesome font's marker is there anyway to call awesome font marker?

```
iconURL = 'marker.svg'
iconSize = new (google.maps.Size)(23, 32)
marker.setIcon
  url: iconURL
  scaledSize: iconSize
```

Comment: I can't see how, as the marker in awesome font is simply a glyph inside of a font, rather than a standalone image

Comment: What it is the point of having the marker for a map if it cannot be placed on a map? I want to know if some one uses the marker on a map and how they do it.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/

Comment: Those are nice yes. but I was wondering awesome font can be used. I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonts cannot be used for marker images.

Though, [nathan-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494182/nathan-m) converted the font to images and you can use those:

https://github.com/nathan-muir/fontawesome-markers

His [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17310434/659634) to the same question had an example of the code.

> You can manually include the JS file, or use npm install
>   fontawesome-markers or bower install fontawesome-markers.
>
> Just include the javascript file fontawesome-markers.min.js and you
>   can use them like so:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: {
        path: fontawesome.markers.EXCLAMATION,
        scale: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 0.2,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: '#f8ae5f',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    },
    clickable: false,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
});
```