# Google Maps v3 FontAwesome5

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am trying to create a googleMap that uses dynamic fontAwesome markers

I can't seem to be able to set 'Font Awesome 5 Free' as the font to be used, though.

I can set 'Fontawsome' which works, but is not a webfont (It's a .TTF installed in MY system)

```js
      var marker0 = createMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
        map: map,
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          fillColor: '#F00',
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeWeight: 0,
          scale: 15
        },
        label: {
          fontFamily: "FontAwesome",
          fontWeight: '900',
          text: eval("'\\u"+'f0ab'+"'"),
          color: 'white'
        }
        }, "<h1>Marker 0</h1><p>This is the home marker.</p>");
    });
```

here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robsilva/hxt5jcu5/

It looks like Google Maps is not applying the font-family property to the marker label that I created. The syntax, according to Google's docs, looks correct, but for some reason all style but that is not being applied. Here are some before and after screens where we manually placed that font-family  styling on the right element...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but two points. First, avoid eval() like the plague. If you have it even one place in your code, JS will run slower throughout because it can't optimize not knowing what code will be run. Second, since FA5 has SVG capability, you might look into using it as an image instead of a label on top of a google image.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yeah i am aware of eval()'s drawbacks but I do not know any other way to render that unicode from a var

Answer (score 7):

Just enclose the font family in either double or single quotes.

```
fontFamily: "'Font Awesome 5 Free'" // or '"Font Awesome 5 Fee"'
```

As already cited by rsilva, this seems to be a bug in the API. Simulated in v3.31:

1. It can't handle the spaces which invalidates the font-family attribute.
2. It also doesn't treat the value as string as shown
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhIHH.png)

[**Workaround**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xJar.png)

Comment: thanks! It only worked once i used it alongside fontWeight: '900'  (as shown in the Workaround image). Apparently this is not a bug but a requirement from FA so that they can distinguish between regular, solid, etc..

Answer (score 2):

The problem happened because there's a bug with the GoogleMaps API where fonts with space character in their name don't get set in the marker properties.

I fixed it by loading FA locally and renaming the font to remove all the spaces, i.e. "FontAwesome5Free'. Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: so you downloaded the .svg?

Comment: No, i just needed to rename the font. I am not using the JS integration.

Comment: What exactly did you do?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, check your jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/as0srs2b/1/

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6608b6cbc6.js"></script>
<div id="map_div" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

JS

```
/*
 * declare map as a global variable
 */
var map;

/*
 * use google maps api built-in mechanism to attach dom events
 */
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {

  /*
   * create map
   */
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  /*
   * create infowindow (which will be used by markers)
   */
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  /*
   * marker creater function (acts as a closure for html parameter)
   */
  function createMarker(options, html) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
    if (html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(options.map, this);
      });
    }
    return marker;
  }

  /*
   * add markers to map
   */
  var marker0 = createMarker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillColor: '#F00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 0,
      scale: 15
    },
    label: {
      fontFamily: "FontAwesome",
      fontWeight: '900',
      text: "\uf0ab",
      color: 'white'
    }
    }, "<h1>Marker 0</h1><p>This is the home marker</p>"); 
});
```

You were concatenating the unicode wrong in the label as well as the fontawesome library was missing.

Comment: Thanks for trying but that did not work. It's still pulling from your copy of Fontawesome and not the new library. I copied your code into its own jsdidle: https://jsfiddle.net/robsilva/as0srs2b/ 
Look at it on your phone or a computer that doesn't have FontAwesome and you will see the issue.
Try changing the name of the font from "Fontawesome" to "Font Awesome 5 Free" to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @rsilva that copy is the new library cdn they provide me from the Font Awesome website https://cdn.fontawesome.com/ but you are right it doesn't work with `fontFamily: "Font Awesome 5 Free"'` according to the documentation you have to set the **::before** or **::after** and you can't do that directly to the label property so you will have to do a trick to get the ::before or :: set in the label. Also, you can download the .svg and inject it into the path property of the icon object

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/as0srs2b/1/ . I don't have fontawesome in my local computer. Web fonts have to be injected into the project not the computer. I'm in a companies computer and I don't have anything related to FA here, but you HAVE TO inject either the cdn or the fontawesome web fonts into your project not the computer

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I have updated the jsfidle t o use FA 5x from a CDN and i changed the unicode to one that was created at version 5 as well. As you can see it doesn't load properly:

https://jsfiddle.net/as0srs2b/

Comment: I'm going to try downloading the .svg and injecting it into the path property of the icon object then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not want to customize my normal npm files to ensure easy updates, my solution was to create another `scss` file which is imported into my `app.scss` and uses the idea of @rsilva to fix the problem:

```
/*!
 * Font Awesome Free 5.2.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
 * License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
 */
$fa-font-path: "../webfonts" !default;

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome5Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.eot');
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.woff') format('woff'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome') format('svg');}

.fa,
.fas {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome5Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

Thereby, I have a font family name without whitespaces but still can easily update my bootstrap package without changing any

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same trouble , my map was showing a square icon instead of a nice FontAwesome.
Firstly i've imported the .css and .js from cdnjs.
I've never used Fontawesome before...

I delete everything and create a free account, and generate a "kit link" from https://fontawesome.com

As above, i got an url with a custom UID

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxxx.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

That made the tricks for me when using a label :

```
label: {
     text: '\uf299',
     fontFamily: 'FontAwesome',
     fontSize: '15px',
     color: 'white'
},
```