# Putting a number inside a font awesome icon marker for google maps marker label

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have this google map marker below and I'm using a [font awesome marker icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/map-marker?style=solid) as the label/icon. But using the label property I'm not sure how I can a.) color the marker b.) put a number inside the marker.

I'm following this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375077/using-icon-fonts-as-markers-in-google-maps-v3)

Here is my code

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {
    lat: eventArray[0].Latitude,
    lng: eventArray[0].Longitude
  },
  map: scope.map,
  label: {
    fontFamily: 'Fontawesome',
    text: '\uf041',
    color: '#008489' // this colors the text inside the label, not the marker color
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming what do you want to achieve is the awesomefont marker with a number in it, you can just copy the [SVG path of the awesomefont marker](https://fontawesome.com/icons/map-marker?style=solid) (click download and copy the SVG path, see [license](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)) and use it as `icon`. Then you can change it's color to anything you want. As `label only input the text/color you want.

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function init() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.509865, -0.118092)
    });
    var icon = {
        path: "M172.268 501.67C26.97 291.031 0 269.413 0 192 0 85.961 85.961 0 192 0s192 85.961 192 192c0 77.413-26.97 99.031-172.268 309.67-9.535 13.774-29.93 13.773-39.464 0z", //SVG path of awesomefont marker
        fillColor: '#008489', //color of the marker
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        scale: 0.09, //size of the marker, careful! this scale also affects anchor and labelOrigin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(200,510), //position of the icon, careful! this is affected by scale
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(205,190) //position of the label, careful! this is affected by scale
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      map: map,
      icon: icon,
      label: {
        text: '3', //text inside marker
        color: '#FFFFFF', //color of the text inside marker
      },
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt" style="font-size:60px;position:relative;color:red;"><p style="font-size:16px;position:absolute;margin:0px;paddind:0px;top:13px;left:19px;">3</p></i>
```

https://codepen.io/kalpeshshende/pen/BqZeVL

Comment: so where would this link tag go?

Comment: link tag would go inside head tag.